# Symfony 2 - ACL check permission based on 'separate' roles

Tags: symfony, acl

Let's say we have 3 main roles that are directly bound to the database table `user`: `ROLE_USER`, `ROLE_MODERATOR` and `ROLE_ADMIN`.

BUT, we also got some other roles, which are used for the `Crews` component (see UML below). I use the following roles for actions peformed in a `Crew`: `ROLE_CREW_BOSS`, `ROLE_CREW_LEFTHAND`, `ROLE_CREW_RIGHTHAND`, `ROLE_CREW_MEMBER`.

```
      +----------------+                                     +------------------+
      | users          |                                     | crews            |
      |----------------|                                     |------------------|
      | id             |                                     | id               |
      | username       <---+                                 | name             |
      | password       |   |                             +---> cash             |
      | roles          |   |    +-------------------+    |   | ...              |
      | ...            |   |    | crew_members      |    |   |                  |
      |                |   |    |-------------------|    |   |                  |
      +----------------+   |    | crew_id +--------------+   |                  |
                           +----+ user_id           |        +--------^---------+
                                | roles             |                 |
                                | ...               |    +------------+
                                |                   |    |
                                |                   |    |   +------------------+
                                |                   |    |   | forum_topics     |
                                |                   |    |   |------------------|
                                |                   |    |   | id               |
                                +-------------------+    +---+ crew_id          |
                                                             | title            |
                                                             | description      |
                                                             | ...              |
                                                             |                  |
                                                             |                  |
                                                             |                  |
                                                             +------------------+
```

That is the base structure, I hope that part is clear. Now comes the problem...

**The problem**

Every user with the role `ROLE_MODERATOR` can create `ForumTopic` objects, but not the one where `crew_id` is set, because that one is private for a specific crew. Also, only crew members (which are also users) that have the role `ROLE_CREW_BOSS`, `ROLE_CREW_LEFTHAND` or `ROLE_CREW_RIGHTHAND` can edit the forum topics of their crew. How do I check those kind of complexity? With a `Voter` maybe?

**UPDATE 1**

I have solved the problem for 50%, but it's not solid. I've created a voter specific for the object `Entity\\ForumTopic`.

```
public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $object, array $attributes)
{
    if ($object instanceof ObjectIdentityInterface) {
        if ($object->getType() == 'Entity\\ForumTopic') {

            /**
             * @var Member $member
             */
            $member = $token->getUser();

            $userTable = new UserTable();
            $user = $userTable->getByMember($member);

            $userInCrewTable = new UserInCrewTable();
            $crewMember = $userInCrewTable->getByUser($user);

            if ($crewMember && in_array($crewMember->getRole(), array('boss', 'lefthand', 'righthand'))) {
                return self::ACCESS_GRANTED;
            }
        }
    }

    return self::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
}
```

The only problem here is that I don't use the respective roles, so I can't use the role hierarchy functionality for example. Anyone got a better solution or a improvement on my current solution?

Thanks!

Steffen

Comment: +1 for the database diagram XD

Comment: please tell me, there is a tool to create such realtion-diagramms :)

Comment: @V-Light Now sure what I used, but just google "ASCII diagram", e.x. http://asciiflow.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The default role system of Symfony is role bound to user.** Having a role field in your manyToMany table crew_members does not make sense from this point of view.

What you want is authorization based *on the user* AND *on the crew*, so you should probably use ACL functionality, and use role only for global permission.

```
    $objectIdentity = ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($forumTopic);
    $acl = $aclProvider->createAcl($objectIdentity);

    $securityIdentity = UserSecurityIdentity::fromAccount($user);

    // grant owner access
    $acl->insertObjectAce($securityIdentity, MaskBuilder::MASK_EDIT);
    $aclProvider->updateAcl($acl);
```

(You can check further docs on http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html. You can also use the excellent https://github.com/Problematic/ProblematicAclManagerBundle)

**You combine it with a voter :**

```
function vote(TokenInterface $token, $object, array $attributes)
{
    if ($object instanceof ObjectIdentityInterface) {
        if ($object->getType() == 'Entity\\ForumTopic') {

            /**
             * @var Member $member
             */
            $member = $token->getUser();

            if(in_array('ROLE_MODERATOR', $member->getRoles() && empty($object->getCrew()) {
                return self::ACCESS_GRANTED;
            }

            // inject security component via dependecy injection
            // delegate further check to ACL
            if ($this->container['security']->isGranted('EDIT', $object)) {
                return self::ACCESS_GRANTED;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use Symfony acl:

```
// creating the ACL
$aclProvider = $this->get('security.acl.provider');
$objectIdentity = ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($comment);
$acl = $aclProvider->createAcl($objectIdentity);

$roleSecurityIdentity = new RoleSecurityIdentity('ROLE_CREW');
$securityIdentity = $roleSecurityIdentity;

// grant owner access
$acl->insertObjectAce($securityIdentity, MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER);
$aclProvider->updateAcl($acl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can touch the solution !
You just have to do some few things if you want to check the roles.
First, register your Voter as a service in order to construct it with the security context :

Add this in your services.yml file :

```
services:
    your_app.security.voter.forum_topic_owner:
        class: Your\AppBundle\Security\Authorization\Voter\ForumTopicOwnerVoter
        arguments: ["@security.context"]
        tags:
            - { name: security.vote
```

Now, you will have to define a constructor to get the securityContext and to use it in the vote method :

```
<?php

namespace Your\AppBundle\Security\Authorization\Voter;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\VoterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;

class ForumTopicOwnerVoter implements VoterInterface
{
    /** @var SecurityContext */
    protected $securityContext;

    /**
     * @param SecurityContext     $securityContext SecurityContext is the main entry point of the Security component.

     */
    public function __construct(SecurityContext $securityContext)
    {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function supportsAttribute($attribute)
    {
        return 'FORUM_TOPIC_OWNER' === $attribute;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return $class->getType() == 'Entity\\ForumTopic';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $forumTopic, array $attributes)
    {
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            if ($this->supportsAttribute($attribute) && $this->supportsClass($forumTopic)) {
                $user = $token->getUser();
                if ($user->hasRole('ROLE_CREW_BOSS')
                    or $this->securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_LEFTHAND')
                    ) {
                        return VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED;
                }
            }
        }

        return VoterInterface::ACCESS_DENIED;
    }
}
```

Now, you have a Voter, you have to call it on a ForumTopic object, apparently you know how to do this and it was not your problem, may I suggest you anyway to look around the SecureParam annotation of the well known Jms/SecurityExtraBundle. Here is a way to use it in your controller action :

```
namespace Your\AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;
use JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\Annotation\Secure;
use JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\Annotation\SecureParam;

/**
 * ForumTopic controller.
 *
 */
class ForumTopicController extends Controller

/**
 * Edit an existing forum topic entity.
 *
 * @param Request    $request    An HTTP request.
 * @param ForumTopic $forumTopic A forumTopic entity.
 *
 * @Secure(roles="ROLE_CREW")
 * @SecureParam(name="forumTopic", permissions="FORUM_TOPIC_OWNER")
 * @ParamConverter("forumTopic", class="YourAppBundle:ForumTopic")
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, ForumTopic $forumTopic)
{
    //Add here your logic
}
```

I hope it has been helpful to you!

Good luck !

Cheers.